# Cantor Function Clarification

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, cantor-set, hausdorff-measure

I am reading some lecture notes and came across the Cantor Function. However, I have some questions about it after reading.

Recall the Cantor set $C \subseteq [0, 1]$ is compact, has Hausdorff dimension $\alpha = \frac{\ln 2}{\ln 3}$ and $H^\alpha$ denotes the Hausdorff measure of dimension $\alpha$.
We define the Cantor function as:
$$
f(x) = \frac{H^\alpha(C \cap [0, x])}{H^\alpha(C)}.
$$
Intuitively, this is the fraction of the Cantor set that lies to the left of $x$. Now define the function
$$
g(x) = \inf\{ y: f(y) = x \}.
$$
It can be observes that $f(g(x)) = x$ as $f$ is increasing and continuous and thus the infimum is achieved. The lecture note then claims $g$ is not continuous and I would like to understand the reasoning behind it.

**In particular, I would like to understand why:**
$$
g(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{3}
$$
and
$$
g(y) \geq \frac{2}{3}
$$
for any $y > \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint.  Here is a picture of $f$.
[image: Cantor staircase]

In particular, you need to know $f(x) = \frac12$ for all $x \in [\frac13,\frac23]$.

Comment: I suppose the fact that $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x \in [\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}]$ is not very explicit from the Hausdorff measure definition of the Cantor function?

Comment: Of course (a) $C \cap (\frac13,\frac23) = \varnothing$; (b) $H^\alpha(\{x\}) = 0$ for any $x$; (c) $H^\alpha(C \cap [0,\frac13]) = \frac12 H^\alpha(C)$.  What else do you need?  Well, yes, you do need the hard part which is $H^\alpha(C) \ne 0$.  That is in Hausdorff's original paper.