# A Holder-continuous function differentiable a.e. is absolutely continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, holder-spaces, absolute-continuity

Let $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Holder-continuous function of an exponent $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and differentiable a.e. at the same time.

Assume further that the derivative $f'$ is integrable on $[0,1]$.

Then I wonder if $f$ is absolutely continuous as well.

Holder-continuity excludes counterexamples like Cantor functions, I believe. But I cannot proceed further.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Cantor function as defined in [its Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) is Hölder-continuous for $\alpha = \frac{\ln 2}{\ln 3}$ (a proof can be found here for example: [Proof Clarification for Cantor Function is Holder Continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4619736/1104384)), almost everywhere differentiable, of derivative $0$ almost everywhere thus of integrable derivative, but is not absolutely continuous.

Comment: Oh my.....it is so surprising and against intuition....Thank you so much for your answer....